# Unable to use all_objects in procedure to fetch other Schema data

Tags: oracle

I have a procedure where I am using `all_objects` view to fetch Objects of some other owner (Schema) XYZ. The procedure doesn't return the expected data, but when I run the query separately (not through the procedure), it does return the data. I am guessing it is some permission issue. Not able to figure it out yet. Please help.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE clearTables(in_parameter int, out_para out varchar)  as 


l_V_Sql   long;
l_V_Sql2   long;

l_v_tab   long;

 CURSOR temp_Data     IS
     SELECT  object_name FROM all_objects WHERE owner = 'XYZ'  AND object_type =   'TABLE' AND created < SYSDATE-in_parameter;

         file UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;

           BEGIN

              Open temp_Data;

              file := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(UPPER('Test_dir'), 'Test_XYZ.txt', 'w');      

              LOOP
              FETCH temp_Data INTO l_v_tab;
              UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(file, in_parameter);
         --     dbms_output.put_line('inside');
              EXIT WHEN temp_Data%notfound;
          --     UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(file,'outside');

              UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(file, l_v_tab);


              l_v_sql := 'DROP TABLE XYZ.'||l_v_tab||' PURGE';
              l_v_sql2 := 'DROP SEQUENCE XYZ.SEQ_'||l_v_tab;


              EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_v_Sql;
              Begin
              EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_v_Sql2;
              EXCEPTION
                 WHEN OTHERS THEN
                 IF SQLCODE != -2289 THEN
                 RAISE;
                 END IF;
              END;


              END LOOP;
              UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(file);


              CLOSE temp_Data;
              out_para:=  'Drop Succeed';
            EXCEPTION
              WHEN OTHERS THEN
              out_para:=  ( l_v_tab ||' : '||SQLERRM);

              CLOSE temp_Data;

  --         END; 

         end clearTables;
```

Answer (score 1):

> trunc(to_date(created, 'DD/MM/YYYY')) < trunc(TO_DATE(SYSDATE-60, 'DD/MM/YYYY'));

This is wrong. Using **`TO_DATE`** on a `DATE` will:

- first convert the date to string using **TO_CHAR**
- and then convert it back to date using **TO_DATE**

based on the **locale-specific NLS settings**. So, it is a bug in your code.

You need to use **TO_DATE** to convert a string literal to DATE.

Given that `created_date` is a DATE data type, you could simply so it as:

```
created_date < SYSDATE - 60
```

See what happens when you use TO_DATE on a DATE column:

```
SQL> EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
  2  SELECT * FROM dual
  3  WHERE to_date(SYSDATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY') > to_date(SYSDATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY') -1;

Explained.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 3752461848

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |      |     1 |     2 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  FILTER            |      |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| DUAL |     1 |     2 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE@!),'DD/MM/YYYY')>TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(S
              YSDATE@!),'DD/MM/YYYY')-1)

15 rows selected.

SQL>
```

It was transformed to **TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE@!),'DD/MM/YYYY')**

Comment: thanks for pointing this out, but my code works if I change owner in the query to my current user. It just doesn't work when I change the owner

Comment: *doesn't work* is not an acceptable error. What actually happens? Does it throw any error? Or, you get no rows?

Comment: It returns no rows in procedure, but same query returns data (150 rows) when i execute it separately

Comment: Post your procedure code. And did you modify the query as I suggested.